# Lint (CLang) complaints on 'override' in specialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, clang, overriding, template-specialization

The following sample code compiles cleanly in MSVC 2012:

```
struct S1
{
    virtual void f() {}
};

template<typename T> struct S2 : S1
{
    void f() override {}
};

template<> void S2<int>::f() override {}
```

However, when I run PC-Lint Plus (which is based on CLang) on the code, it reports errors:

```
template<> void S2<int>::f()^ override {}
test.cpp(11): error 4645: expected ';' at end of declaration
template<> void S2<int>::f() override {}^
test.cpp(11): error 4933: expected ';' after top level declarator
```

Incidentally, if I remove the `override` specifier, lint emits a note that it is missing.

Is that a lint/CLang bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should not have `virtual`/`override`/`final` in definition, only in declaration.

Comment: So is MSVC2012 wrong in accepting the `override`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need the `override` in the function declaration, not in the out of class definition. Just remove it:

```
template<> void S2<int>::f() {}
```